# NoMethodError: undefined method `gsub' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I added a condition option to my thinking sphinx search and I am now getting a `` NoMethodError: undefined method `gsub' for nil:NilClass ``

```
        @users = User.search(params[:search].gsub(/\s+/, ' | '),
        :geo => [current_user.latitude * Math::PI / 180.0, current_user.longitude * Math::PI / 180.0],
        :with  => {:geodist => 0.0..100_000.0},
        :conditions => {:ethnicity => params[:ethnicity], :religion => params[:religion]},
        :order => 'geodist ASC', :without => {:user_id => current_user.id})


    end      
    render 'users/index', layout: 'new_application'    

  end
```

Comment: Have you done any debugging, at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
params[:search].gsub(/\s+/, ' | ')
```

If the params[:search] is nil then this would error.  Either make sure that their is a value or extract this into another class called UserSearcher that takes care of this business logic.